# AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 please rectify this error

Tags: python

this is my code

```py
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=15)
clf = knn.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
acc_knb_model = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, multi_class="OVR")*100
acc_knb_model
```

Comment: Please provide more information: In which line does the error happen? How do you create `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_test` and `y_test`?